# Como gerar duas páginas com DOMPDF no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

Tenho que gerar o PDF de uma 'carteirinha', e tenho que colocar a frente e verso no mesmo arquivo.
Tenho o seguinte fonte para gerar a parte da frente:

```
$nome = $cliente->nome.'.pdf';
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('cliente.print', array('cliente' => $cliente));
$customPaper = array(0,0,153.00,240.90);// tamanho personalizado
return $pdf->setPaper($customPaper, 'landscape')->stream($nome);
```

A geração sai perfeita como na foto abaixo, agora quero adicionar uma segunda página logo abaixo e colocar a imagem do verso.

Já pesquisei e tentei passar a segunda página no array do tamanho personalizado mas não consegui resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você ja tentou gerar esta carteirinha com HTML e CSS? Cada carteirinha podia ser uma div e você pode usar um <br> para quebrar elas. Creio que seria uma boa solução.

Comment: Sim a primeira página fiz totalmente com HTML e CSS, porque os dados viram dinamicamente do banco. Porém a segunda página é uma imagem.

Comment: A solução para sua pergunta você encontra aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746958/dompdf-adding-a-new-page-to-pdf/43911627#43911627 Mas acredito que seja o caso adicionar uma nova <div> e continuar estilizando.

Comment: Já pensou em [page-break-after](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)?

Comment: Sim foi resolvido usando page-break. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado nas resposta do SOen dos usuários [cotton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43911627/2932525) e [BrianS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768573/2932525):

O DOMPDF lida com paginação automaticamente. Se você quer forçar uma quebra de página pode usar o estilo CSS `page-break-before: always;` ou `page-break-after: always;`

Dessa formar você pode incluir um elemento para quebrar a página:

CSS

```
.page-break { page-break-before: always; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Ou adicionar o estilo em algum elemento existente.